# 'Unable to process source' error

Tags: 16.04, ros

I am installing ros in Ubuntu 16.04 and all went well until the following command

> rosdep update

The error I am getting is as follows

> reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
>
> ERROR: unable to process source
>   [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
>     
>   (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)
>
> ERROR: unable to process source
>   [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
>     
>   (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)
>
> ERROR: unable to process source
>   [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
>     
>   (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)
>
> ERROR: unable to process source
>   [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
>     
>   (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
>
> ERROR: unable to process source
>   [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
>     Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
>
> error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution> Query rosdistro
>   index
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
>
> ERROR: error loading sources list:    
>   (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>

I am installing using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu). Issue is happening at command 2 of 1.5;

I edited the **/etc/environment** file with export statements and no issue with such proxy statements.

Is there any need to place the export proxy statements any where?

How to fix this issue and update properly?

Comment: I assume you are installing using an instruction. so please post a link to it.

Comment: Yeah @davidbaumann. I edited the question